# RxJava Subscribing to many observables does not trigger onNext() for all subscribers?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

When I create 5 observables and subscribe to each of them with separate subscriber, intuitively I thought that each subscriber would get its observables' corresponding data, emitted via onNext() call:

```
val compositeSubscription = CompositeDisposable()

fun test() {

        for (i in 0..5) {
            compositeSubscription.add (Observable.create<String>(object : ObservableOnSubscribe<String> {
                override fun subscribe(emitter: ObservableEmitter<String>) {
                    emitter.onNext("somestring")
                    emitter.onComplete()
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        Logger.i("testIt onNext")
                    }, {
                        Logger.i("testIt onError")
                    }))
        }
}
```

However, what I see is one or two "testIt onNext" in the log.

Now, when I add the delay in subscribers' onNext(), all 6 subscribers onNext() are getting called.

This seems like some racy condition, when some of the subscribers are not fast enough to catch up on their data. Just how this happens evades me, as subscribe() should be called after Subscriber is up and running.

Would be grateful for any tips on this.

Comment: you probably don't want to subscribeOn the main thread

Comment: Yes this is true, changed to Schedulers.computation(), and observing on main thread now, but still the same log.

Comment: Judging from this code every subscriber should print "testIt onNext". Are you sure it is not getting printed? Maybe Android Studio is collapsing identical lines? Have you tried printing something different for each subscriber?

Comment: @gpunto you are absolutely right, logcat collapses identical lines (with identical timestamp), and as it happens quickly that's my case. If you write it as an answer I'll accept, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from this code every subscriber should print "testIt onNext". Are you sure it is not getting printed? Maybe Android Studio is collapsing identical lines? Have you tried printing something different for each subscriber?